# Why we are breaking coconut before start any new-work?

Tags: scripture

In our Hinduism, there is one Custom, that we break the coconut before start any new-work, like opening of shop and so many other-things, So what is Important of breaking a Coconut before starting new things,
Is there any evidence in our Scriptures which claimed this thing? 
Please share your Idea.!!
Thanks.